# Проверка email на существование python

Tags: python, email, flask, smtp, протоколы

Нужно проверить email на существование. Не на корректность написания, а именно что почта действительно существует. Как этот сервис: https://2ip.ru/mail-checker/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559436/how-do-i-validate-the-mx-record-for-a-domain-in-python

Comment: @SergeyGlukhov, извините, не могу разобраться. Много информации, чёткого решения не прописали, а английским я владею плохо. Можете, пожалуйста, выделить суть решения?

Answer (score 1):

Вот то , как я решил эту проблему :

```
from validate_email import validate_email

login = 'вашлогин'

is_valid = validate_email(login, verify=True)

if is_valid == True:

    print('Такой логин есть')
```

Comment: Ваш скрипт проверяет на правильость написания мейла, так же нужно проверять днс и мх
Но он потвредит почту. которая не существует, просто подходит под правильность написания